# Entity Framework gives "type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type" error when using class with nullable fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm hoping to simplify my code somewhat by using a class with generic fields, but EF is protesting and giving the error message

> The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

Here's my simplified code. Basically, I'm trying to hold additional data about numeric attributes.

```
public class Equipment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ComplexValue<int> ShaftSpeed { get; set; }
    public ComplexValue<Single> ShaftSize { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexValue<T> where T : struct, IComparable
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public T? DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

So that each numeric property of Equipment can have a default value, but the default could be null.

The underlying database structure for the Equipment table has fields

- Id (int, not null)
- ShaftSpeed_Value (int, not null)
- ShaftSpeed_DefaultValue (int, null)
- ShaftSize_Value (real, not null)
- ShaftSize_DefaultValue (real, null)

I can create an instance of Equipment and set values, but when I try to persist it to the database I get this error.

However, if I create a class per data type:

```
public class Equipment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ComplexIntegerValue ShaftSpeed { get; set; }
    public ComplexSingleValue ShaftSize { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexIntegerValue
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultValue { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexSingleValue
{
    public Single Value { get; set; }
    public Single? DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

it works fine.

I'm constraining the generic type to be a struct, as I've seen suggested but this didn't help.

Any ideas or advice welcomed!

Thanks

Doug

Comment: That seems like a lot of complexity to persist in your database, and I don;t think it will persist how you expect it to (e.g. _each_ instance will have a default value).  Perhaps you should simplify the EF model and map to a more complex domain model?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Yes, each instance does need a default value in our particular case. Be that as it may, the name of the field is somewhat irrelevant. It could easily be, for instance, the units of measure for the numeric value. So the question remains. Why is the generic class not acceptable to EF? In fact, when I looked at the SQL generated by EF in this case, it only involved the key field "Id". The other fields weren't even mentioned!